# MongoDB query gives wierd & incorrect results

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB 2.0.2.

When I run the following query I get 1 document.

```js
 { 
 "value.Other.part" : { "$regex" : "/*\\QPart\\E/*" , "$options" : "i"} ,
 "value.Other.wtype" : { "$regex" : "/*\\QAAA\\E/*" , "$options" : "i"} ,
 "value.Other._name" : { "$regex" : "/*others/*" , "$options" : "i"} , 
 "value.Other.type" : { "$regex" : "/*\\QELECTRONICS\\E/*" , "$options" : "i"}
 }
```

Returned docs:

```js
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("529720a0c50fff688e143dfe"),
  "value" : {
    "Other" : {
      "_id" : ObjectId("529720a0c50fff688e143dfb"),
      "type" : "ELECTRONICS",
      "_name" : "others",
      "part" : "Part Number Third Set",
      "wtype" : "AAA"
    },
    "AType" : {
      "_id" : ObjectId("529720a0c50fff688e143dfc"),
      "compunit" : "BBB Unit"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run this query I get 2 documents.

```js
{ 
 "value.Other.part" : { "$regex" : "/*\\QPart\\E/*" , "$options" : "i"} ,
 "value.Other.wtype" : { "$regex" : "/*\\QAAA\\E/*" , "$options" : "i"} ,
 "value.Other._name" : { "$regex" : "/*others/*" , "$options" : "i"} , 
 "value.AType.compunit" : { "$regex" : "/*\\QBBB Unit\\E/*" , "$options" : "i"} , 
 "value.Other.type" : { "$regex" : "/*\\QELECTRONICS\\E/*" , "$options" : "i"}
}
```

Returned docs:

```js
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52947a75c50f75b6a5f86bc6"),
  "value" : {
    "Other" : {
      "_id" : ObjectId("52947a75c50f75b6a5f86bc3"),      
      "type" : "PRODUCT IDENTIFICATION",
      "_name" : "others",
      "part" : "Part Number Third Set",
      "wtype" : "AAA"
    },
    "AType" : {      
      "_id" : ObjectId("52947a75c50f75b6a5f86bc4"),
      "compunit" : "BBB Unit"
    }
  }
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("529720a0c50fff688e143dfe"),
  "value" : {
    "Other" : {
      "_id" : ObjectId("529720a0c50fff688e143dfb"),
      "type" : "ELECTRONICS",
      "_name" : "others",
      "part" : "Part Number Third Set",
      "wtype" : "AAA"
    },
    "AType" : {
      "_id" : ObjectId("529720a0c50fff688e143dfc"),
      "compunit" : "BBB Unit"
    }
  }
}
```

And one document doesn't satisfy the query.

Could someone explain what is wrong?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the returned documents?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `/*\\Q` and `\\E/*` parts of the regular expressions?

Comment: \Q marks the regex quote and \E marks the end of the quote. Am trying to do String contains operation basically.

Comment: string contains is the default for regular expression.  I just cut-n-paste your query with your documents and I get only one returned in each case.  are you sure about your results?  what version are you using?

Comment: Am using MongoDB 2.0.2. I am sure, am getting different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is because of the `number of regex in the query`. Before version 2.1.0, it seems you cannot use more than 4 regex in a query. [MongoDB JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-969)